# Received error when processing identity validation filter

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2013

I get this error:
 Received error when processing identity validation filter.
when I try to connect to team foundation server, it used to work fine.
I tried to open my project in visual studio online and selected my project then clicked "open in visual studio". Unfortunately the same error appears. 
I'm trying to check-in my files.
thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your TFS server is down. Your best option is to either contact your on-site TFS administrator, or contact your TFS hosting provider.

There is likely nothing you can do locally to restore connection. If you have zero network connectivity, Visual Studio will report that you're disconnected rather than showing this error message.